# Gasoline generator + Peltier configuration

Tags: amperage, peltier, power-consumption, cooling, power-generation

I have a DIY cooler box with Peltier element 12V/3A/27 watts and want to connect via power supply to gasoline generator with output 600W at 5A max.

Would that be a problem and not supply my Peltier and need bigger amperage generator?

Comment: That generator is more than capable of powering the Peltier device but it is a horrendous waste of energy. The efficiency of each stage will be very poor. Will your beer - or your conscience - have a taste of gasoline?

Comment: The generator is way bigger than needed, but you will need to convert the 120V AC down to 12V DC. The converter will draw approximately 0.3A from your generator because the voltage is higher.

Comment: The gasoline generator is 220V ( european ) and 12V output also. But I must look for generator with equal amperage with the Peltier module or must be bigger ? The gasoline gen. will work about a hour untill the desired temperature in the cool box is achieved.

Comment: Thought experiment: if I connect a 10 W lamp to my national grid which has a peak capacity > 5,000 MW will it blow the lamp? Why?

Comment: No it wont blow

Comment: You can power a compressor refrigerator cool box with that amount of power. Which is way more efficient, gets your beer cooler in a shorter time and does not use as much gasoline so it will save your money in the long run. On a side note, shouldn't resource wasting topics be offtopic?

Comment: Luke I've already buy all the stuff for the Peltier cooler. Only the box not and the generator. I will use this cooler box in the nature so thats why I ask for the gasoline generator. What you mean by "resource wasting topics to be offtopics"